# Invalid BSON field name : when trying to insert HashMap in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

This line :

```
instance.getRubricDocumentMap().put(new Rubric(), new ArrayList<NewsletterDocument>());
```

is causing this error :

```
com.oxway.store.api.exceptions.StoreException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name com.oxway.report.models.Rubric@188993df
    at com.oxway.store.mongodb.MongoDBStoreDao.create(MongoDBStoreDao.java:122)
```

when i am trying to insert the `instance` object in MongoDB.

Here is the instance class :

```
@Identity(name = "identity", type = String.class)
public class NewsletterInstance extends Definition {
    protected NewsletterStatus status;
    protected String newsletterDefinitionId;
    protected String subtitle;

    protected Map<Rubric, List<NewsletterDocument>> rubricDocumentMap;

    public Map<Rubric, List<NewsletterDocument>> getRubricDocumentMap() {
        return rubricDocumentMap;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public void setRubricDocumentMap(Map<Rubric, List<NewsletterDocument>> rubricDocumentMap) {
        this.rubricDocumentMap = rubricDocumentMap;
    }

    public String getNewsletterDefinitionId() {
        return newsletterDefinitionId;
    }

    public void setNewsletterDefinitionId(String newsletterDefinitionId) {
        this.newsletterDefinitionId = newsletterDefinitionId;
    }

    public NewsletterStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(NewsletterStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public NewsletterInstance() {

    }
}
```

Here is the rubric class :

```
public class Rubric {
    protected String id;

    protected String title;
    protected String description;

    public Rubric() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    };

    public Rubric(String title, List<NewsletterDocument> documents) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Any idea of what is the problem here and why i can't insert this object in MongoDB? This is the firs time i'm using a HashMap so maybe there is something i don't know.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the contents of the `Map` or at least the keys.  This may help: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions  You didn't say what version of MongoDB you're using but you can change the version of the documentation on the page.

Comment: Actually the problem was having an object as key, i changed it to put String instead and it works